# why does boilerplate Dockerfile define base but not use it?

Tags: docker

I've seen a number of template Dockerfiles constructed like this:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:5.0 AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80

[A bunch of restore/build/publish instructions]

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT yada yada
```

What I don't understand is how that improves or is a better starting point than the below:

```
[Same exact restore/build/publish instructions]

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:5.0 AS final
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT yada yada
```

Is there something here that I don't understand or am missing?

Comment: See [multistage builds](https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/multistage-build/)

Comment: Semantically, both are the same. Both should have the same number of layers.

Comment: I feel like I've seen some variants of this that have the intermediate stages build `FROM base` as well, and that would give you a place to install common packages or other OS-level dependencies.

Comment: @Turing85 thanks, that's what I was thinking. David Maze, your thoughts make sense, but I would ask (not you, but those responsible for the template) whether this just-in-case added ceremony makes sense. Are not those developers doing the more uncommon variants the very ones most comfortably able to add the necessary code to the top of the Dockerfile?